# How to create all possible unique lists

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, unique

I am writing a short program for my basketball team. I have gotten Coach to divide the players into lists that correspond to a specific position. (List1 = Point Guards)

Using these lists, I want to create an output with all possible "valid" lineups.

Currently, I have written a basic program that selects 5 unique people from each list

How can I cause this to loop in such a way that all "Valid" configurations of 5 players are printed out?

Any suggestions or direction is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import random    

list1 = ['Gabe', 'taylor', 'kyle', 'jay']
list2 = ['Gabe', 'Taylor', 'Kyle', 'Jay', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Chris', 'Bruno', 'David']
list3 = ['Gabe', 'Taylor', 'Kyle', 'Jay', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Chris', 'Bruno', 'David']
list4 = ['Kyle', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Bruno', 'Drew', 'Chris']
list5 = ['James', 'John', 'Brendan','Tim', 'Drew' ]
FinalList = []


position_lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]

for position_list in position_lists: # for every position

    found_my_guy = False

    while not found_my_guy: # keep looping till I find my guy

        selectedPerson = position_list[ random.randint( 0,len(position_list) -1 ) ]

        if selectedPerson not in FinalList: # only append guys that are not duplicates
            FinalList.append(selectedPerson)
            found_my_guy = True # exit while loop and go to next `lineup'


for person in FinalList:
    sys.stdout.write(person + '\n')
```

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions for the followup question, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234030/keeping-only-unique-instances-of-lists-whose-only-difference-is-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [(a,b,c,d,e) for a in list1 
                    for b in list2 
                        for c in list3 
                            for d in list4 
                                for e in list5 
                                    if len(set((a,b,c,d,e))) == 5]
s = set(map(lambda e: tuple(sorted(e)), l))
print len(s)

>>> 970
```

EDIT: maybe even better

```
s = set([frozenset((a,b,c,d,e)) for a in list1 
                for b in list2 
                    for c in list3 
                        for d in list4 
                            for e in list5 
                                if len(set((a,b,c,d,e))) == 5])
print len(s)

>>> 970
```

Comment: `a != b != c != d != e` does not imply a-e are unique. Try `1 != 2 != 1`. (It's `True`).

Comment: what do I do with the other question? I cant delete it because it has answers

Comment: I used 

`for lineup in s:
    print(lineup)` 

Is there a simple way to make the printout always be in the order of lists?

Comment: 'print s' should do it

Answer (score 4):

We can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the cartesian product of the lists then filter out any results that have duplicates:

```
from itertools import product

list1 = ['Gabe', 'Taylor', 'Kyle', 'Jay']
list2 = ['Gabe', 'Taylor', 'Kyle', 'Jay', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Chris', 'Bruno', 'David']
list3 = ['Gabe', 'Taylor', 'Kyle', 'Jay', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Chris', 'Bruno', 'David']
list4 = ['Kyle', 'James', 'John', 'Tyde','Bruno', 'Drew', 'Chris']
list5 = ['James', 'John', 'Brendan','Tim', 'Drew' ]

FinalList = []

for x in product(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5):
    # check for duplicates
    if len(set(x)) == 5 and set(x) not in FinalList:
        FinalList.append(set(x))


# to print
for x in FinalList:
    print x
```

There are more efficient ways to calculate such a list I believe, but this code runs basically instantly on my modest laptop.

Also, to address your second question, basically you were doing it the wrong way. In theory taking random guesses would allow you to create all possible sets of names, but only has you approached infinity. In practice it would of course be much sooner, but still a lot less efficient than just generating the list outright.

Edit: Also, as a final note:

```
>>> len(FinalList)
970
```

(This list may not be real helpful...)

Comment: How should I print out the contents of Final List? I'm not sure how to know what something is in python...

Comment: See the updated code for an example of printing it line by line.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect, the same set can appear more than once

Comment: all lists are unique but are not sets. check out the followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234030/keeping-only-unique-instances-of-lists-whose-only-difference-is-order

Answer (score 1):

use  `if s2 in FinalList`  to check if  s2 is aready picked in FinalList,

Answer (score 1):

```
playerLists = tuple(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5)
masterSet = set(list1 + list2 + list3 + list4 + list5)

from random import choice
def FindPlayer(playerList):
    while True:
        randomPlayer = choice(playerList)
        if randomPlayer in masterSet:
            masterSet.remove(randomPlayer)
            return randomPlayer

for playerList in playerLists:
    print FindPlayer(playerList)
```